# R Studio not plotting when adding par

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

I'm following along with an R book and some of the examples aren't actually plotting anything for me in R Studio (I'm running 3.6.1 of R). Here is the code I'm running:

```
dose  <- c(20, 30, 40, 45, 60)
drugA <- c(16, 20, 27, 40, 60)
drugB <- c(15, 18, 25, 31, 40)
opar <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
par(pin=c(2, 3))
par(lwd=2, cex=1.5)
par(cex.axis=.75, font.axis=3)
plot(dose, drugA, type="b", pch=19, lty=2, col="red")
plot(dose, drugB, type="b", pch=23, lty=6, col="blue", bg="green")
par(opar)
```

But I can't see any errors, nothing shows up in the Plots pane, and troubleshooting has been shooting in the dark... I found by trial and error that this code actually produces a chart:

```
dose  <- c(20, 30, 40, 45, 60)
drugA <- c(16, 20, 27, 40, 60)
drugB <- c(15, 18, 25, 31, 40)
plot(dose, drugA, type="b", pch=19, lty=2, col="red")
plot(dose, drugB, type="b", pch=23, lty=6, col="blue", bg="green")
```

So removing all the `par()` related lines makes a plot actually show up... My assumption is that the book I'm following is for a different version of R, but I'm such a noob that I don't know.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try it in the RGui console and see if that makes any difference. That will at least determine where the issue lies, whether R or the plot pane in RStudio. `par` and a basic `plot` are long-established functions so I don't think they should have changed much.

Comment: That was my issue! When I did the lines one by one in the console it worked. Why doesn't it work to run multiple lines in a file?

Comment: Try `ctrl + shift + enter` to run all lines, i.e. to "source" your script (or use the "source" button). Note that this halts on errors.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what my problem was. I was trying to run all the lines of a file in the upper left pane by hitting command + enter BUT that would only run the last line, not everything in the file. For it to work like I expected, I needed to do Shift+Command+P, That runs everything in the file. Sigh there went 2 hours banging my head against the wall!

I'm a total noob at RStudio!

Thanks @thelatemail for the hint that put me on the right track.